# Get values by comparing comma separated string

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

Languages table

| id | languages |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | Spanish |
| 3 | Hindi |
| 4 | Portuguese |

Users Table

| userid | languages |
| --- | --- |
| 1421 | 1,3 |
| 1422 | 2,3,4 |

I want the output like this

| userid | languages_names |
| --- | --- |
| 1421 | English,Hindi |
| 1422 | Spanish,Hindi,Portuguese |

Comment: The db requires normalization and comma separated data should not be stored for any relation. However you can check `find_in_set` for the solution in the mean while.

Comment: Can you please mention the query format?

Comment: I have tried this type. "SELECT group_concat(languages) FROM languages WHERE id IN(4,5,6)" this is works. but this is not works "SELECT group_concat(languages) FROM languages WHERE id IN(SELECT languages FROM users WHERE id = 1421)

Comment: Try this query `select u.userid, group_concat(l.languages_names) as languages_names from users u join Languages l on find_in_set(l.id,u.languages) > 0 group by u.userid`

Comment: It works fine. Thanks a lot.